# Merge >300 PDF files to a single PDF, error: too many open files

Tags: r, pdf, pdf-generation, qpdf

I would like to merge 500 PDF files in `R`.

Usually `qpdf::pdf_combine` worked fine for a few PDFs, but now I get the error:
`Too many open files`.

I found that this error is related to the fact that `qpdf` opens the files during the process: https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html. There is also a solution with `--keep-files-open=[y|n]`. However, I think this is not implemented in the R package.

Could I modify `pdf_combine` that it works? Or is there a better way to combine many PDF files in `R`?

Comment: I'd use other tools, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2507766/680068. Or if we really want R, then merge iteratively, for example, merge every 100 5 times, then merge 5 into one.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did it iteratively. However, it gets a bit complicated if I merge many fiel via a functions.

Comment: Did you verify it works with the qpdf command line tool?

Comment: No I use qpdf actually only within R